# Excel Interop : Cells.Formula doesn't translate

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-interop

I need to insert a formula in an Excel file that could be open either from an English version of Excel or a French one.
This is what I tried, because I have read that Excel automatically translates local formula names when used with `Range.Formula` :
`xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, "J"].Formula = string.Format("= MEAN(J3:J{0})", i - 1);`

However what I get on a French Excel version is a `#NAME?` error, because the formula is not actually translated.

The problem is fixed if I use :
`xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, "J"].FormulaLocal = string.Format("= MOYENNE(J3:J{0})", i - 1);`

Does anyone know how I can automatically translate the formula name depending on the international parameters, or why "Formula" doesn't work ? I know I could just have a condition based on the application settings, but I would like to find a more universal way to do it.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: I have a vague memory that `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, "J"].value = string.Format("= MEAN(J3:J{0})", i - 1);` might work.

Comment: Hi, just tried it, and it doesn't work (still the same problem)

Comment: Try using AVERAGE instead of MEAN

Comment: Oh my god wow it was only that. I feel really stupid.
Thank you ! :D